# How can we sort the column of jqgrid if row number is true?

Tags: jqgrid

I have set rownumber: true and i am trying to sort it. Is there any attribute in JQGrid to sort this dynamic column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The meaning of `rownumber: true` is: creating the column with the number 1 in the first row, the number 2 in the second row and so on. Even if the user sorts the grid by any column, the first row stay the first one and thus it should contain the same number 1. Because of that, the column `"rn"`, added by the option `rownumber: true`, is **unsortable**. It contains the properties `sortable: false, resizable: false, hidedlg: true, search: false` and some other.